# Is the Panasonic Leica Summilux the same quality as a non-Panasonic Leica summilux?

Tags: lens, optics, panasonic, leica

Is there an advantage to having a Leica Leica lens vs. a Panasonic Leica lens? To my ability to examine them, they look like the same on the inside. Would this be correct? The Leica Leicas are thousands of dollars whereas the Panasonic Leicas are only 1000 tops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are. The only real difference is the primary lens mount and the AF system.

Comment: Keep it courteous please.